# Async await function not ending in the order that it should Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf, dom-to-image

Why is the function convertToPng that I have stated to await for until completion, specifically until the imgOnLoad is entered and the PDF is created, is still being executed simultaneously?

**Actual Results**

[image]

1. "Convert to png function has ended"
2. "Proceeding after convert to png"
3. "Saving PDF INTO COMPUTER"
4. "imgOnLoad event entered"
5. "ATTACHING IMAGE 1"

**Expected Result**

1. "imgOnLoad event entered"
2. "ATTACHING IMAGE 1"
3. "Convert to png function has ended"
4. "Proceeding after convert to png"
5. "Saving PDF INTO COMPUTER"

**Simplified Code**

```
for (let i = 0; i< selected_views.length; i++) {
    $('.loading-text').html("Exporting...");
    $('.loading-count').html((i + 1) + "/" + selected_views.length);
    let node = document.getElementsByClassName('view-container view-grid-' + view_id[1])[0];
    const data = await convertToPng(doc,node,doc_width,doc_height,doc_wh_ratio);
    console.log("Proceeding after convert to png");
}
$('.loading-text').html("Loading...");
$("#loading").hide();
console.log("SAVING PDF INTO COMPUTER"); 
doc.save(dashboard_name + '_' + client_name + '.pdf');


async function convertToPng(doc,page,doc_width,doc_height,doc_wh_ratio) {
            // window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
            // Go to next page
            doc.addPage();
            let chartNodes = page.childNodes;
            for(let i =0; i < chartNodes.length; i++){
                console.log(chartNodes[i]);
                console.log(chartNodes[i].firstChild.firstChild);
                if(chartNodes[i].firstChild.firstChild.tagName == 'TABLE'){
                    (doc.autoTable({ html: chartNodes[i].firstChild.firstChild }));
                }
                else{
                    let options = { "cacheBust":true }
                    let dataUrl = await domtoimage.toPng(page,options);
                    console.log('~~~~~~~~~');
                    console.log(dataUrl);
                    console.log('~~~~~~~~~');
                    img.src = dataUrl;
                    let img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function() {
                        console.log("imgOnLoad event entered");
                        img_wh_ratio = img.width / img.height;
                        if (img_wh_ratio > doc_wh_ratio) {
                            console.log("ATTACHING IMAGE 1");
                            // Add dashboard image to pdf with margins
                            doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 2, 2, doc_width - 4, 0); // Set width as limiting dimension
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("ATTACHING IMAGE 2");
                            // Get margins to centralize horizontally
                            let new_width = img.width * doc_height / img.height;
                            let total_margin = doc_width - new_width;
                            let side_margin = total_margin / 2;
                            // Add dashboard image to pdf with margins
                            doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', side_margin + 2, 2, 0, doc_height - 4); // Set height as limiting dimension
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("Convert to png function has ended");
        }
```

Comment: `img.onload = function()` is an event, nothing making that await in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `onload` event inside your `convertToPng()` function is happening asynchronous. By itself it does not return a promise so you need to put the loading procedure in another function which returns a promise alongside the image.

This way you can use the `await` keyword and await the actual image result - `img = await loadImage(dataUrl);`.

For example:

```
function loadImage(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = path;
    img.onload = () => {
      resolve(img);
    }
    img.onerror = e => {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}
async function convertToPng(doc, page, doc_width, doc_height, doc_wh_ratio) {
  // window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
  // Go to next page
  doc.addPage();
  let chartNodes = page.childNodes;
  for (let i = 0; i < chartNodes.length; i++) {
    console.log(chartNodes[i]);
    console.log(chartNodes[i].firstChild.firstChild);
    if (chartNodes[i].firstChild.firstChild.tagName == 'TABLE') {
      (doc.autoTable({
        html: chartNodes[i].firstChild.firstChild
      }));
    } else {
      let options = {
        "cacheBust": true
      }
      let dataUrl = await domtoimage.toPng(page, options);
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~');
      console.log(dataUrl);
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~');
      let img = await loadImage(dataUrl);
      console.log("imgOnLoad event entered");
      img_wh_ratio = img.width / img.height;
      if (img_wh_ratio > doc_wh_ratio) {
        console.log("ATTACHING IMAGE 1");
        // Add dashboard image to pdf with margins
        doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 2, 2, doc_width - 4, 0); // Set width as limiting dimension
      } else {
        console.log("ATTACHING IMAGE 2");
        // Get margins to centralize horizontally
        let new_width = img.width * doc_height / img.height;
        let total_margin = doc_width - new_width;
        let side_margin = total_margin / 2;
        // Add dashboard image to pdf with margins
        doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', side_margin + 2, 2, 0, doc_height - 4); // Set height as limiting dimension
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("Convert to png function has ended");
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works!! But do you mind elaboring a bit more on why I cant await img.onload?

Comment: No problem Yeo - glad I could help! =) The `await` keyword's solely purpose is 'awaiting' the result of a `Promise`. The `onload` event however is just an event that eventually gets dispatched and it does not ever resolve a Promise by itself. So `await img.onload` won't ever resolve (or reject if something fails) as it never returns a Promise.

Comment: In that case shouldnt the function code just stop running rather than continuing to execute code beyond this point as it should be waiting for a promise that never resolves?

I also tried wrapping the onload event within a promise itself and will resolve(true) when the onload event is entered and the image is added to the pdf. However this didn't work doesn't work as well?